# Oracle optimizer wrongly estimates cardinality as 1 for public synonyms

Tags: oracle, optimization, execution-plan, oracle-10g

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    d.devicename,
    d.template,
    d.deleteflag,
    SUM(isUnexpected(gv.value,sv.param1,sv.param2,sv.comparator,sv.operator) ) totalDeviation
FROM
    vm_wells_situ s
INNER JOIN devices d 
    ON upper(s.well) = upper(d.devicename)
    AND d.deleteflag IS NULL
    AND d.template = 'APT'
INNER JOIN zafiro_srv_wells z 
    ON s.well = z.name
INNER JOIN district t 
    ON z.batteryDistrict = t.cod_zafiro
    AND t.ug = 'GSJ'
    AND t.management = 'GOP-2'
INNER JOIN equipment eq 
    ON z.batteryEquipment = eq.cod_zafiro
    AND eq.deleted = 0
INNER JOIN station st 
    ON z.battery = st.cod_zafiro
    AND st.deleted = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN suggested_values sv 
    ON sv.tecnologia = d.template
    AND sv.type = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN general_values gv 
    ON sv.variable = gv.name
    AND d.devicename = gv.device
WHERE
    s.type = 'specialWell'
GROUP BY
    d.devicename,
    d.template,
    d.deleteflag
```

Which generates the following execution plan:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Inst   |IN-OUT|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |                       |     1 |   246 |   230   (2)| 00:00:03 |        |      |
|   1 |  WINDOW SORT                    |                       |     1 |   246 |   230   (2)| 00:00:03 |        |      |
|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY                 |                       |     1 |   246 |   230   (2)| 00:00:03 |        |      |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER           |                       |     1 |   246 |   228   (1)| 00:00:03 |        |      |
|   4 |     VIEW                        |                       |     1 |   205 |   226   (1)| 00:00:03 |        |      |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| ZAFIRO_SRV_WELLS      |     1 |    37 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS              |                       |     1 |   331 |   226   (1)| 00:00:03 |        |      |
|   7 |        MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN     |                       |     1 |   294 |   224   (1)| 00:00:03 |        |      |
|   8 |         MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN    |                       |     1 |   266 |   221   (1)| 00:00:03 |        |      |
|   9 |          MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN   |                       |     1 |   242 |   218   (1)| 00:00:03 |        |      |
|* 10 |           HASH JOIN             |                       |     1 |   215 |   215   (1)| 00:00:03 |        |      |
|  11 |            NESTED LOOPS OUTER   |                       |     1 |   172 |   196   (1)| 00:00:03 |        |      |
|  12 |             REMOTE              | DEVICES               |     1 |    52 |   180   (1)| 00:00:03 | SRVESP | R->S |
|  13 |             REMOTE              | SUGGESTED_VALUES      |    17 |  2040 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 | SRVESP | R->S |
|  14 |            REMOTE               | VM_WELLS_SITU         |   595 | 25585 |    18   (0)| 00:00:01 | SRVHIS | R->S |
|  15 |           BUFFER SORT           |                       |     2 |    54 |   199   (1)| 00:00:03 |        |      |
|* 16 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL    | DISTRICT              |     2 |    54 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
|  17 |          BUFFER SORT            |                       |    27 |   648 |   218   (1)| 00:00:03 |        |      |
|* 18 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL     | EQUIPMENT             |    27 |   648 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
|  19 |         BUFFER SORT             |                       |   128 |  3584 |   221   (1)| 00:00:03 |        |      |
|* 20 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL      | STATION               |   128 |  3584 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
|* 21 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN         | ZAFIRO_SRV_WELLS_IDX1 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |
|  22 |     REMOTE                      | GENERAL_VALUES        |     1 |    41 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | SRVESP | R->S |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - filter("Z"."BATTERYDISTRICT" IS NOT NULL AND "Z"."BATTERY" IS NOT NULL AND 
              "Z"."BATTERYEQUIPMENT" IS NOT NULL AND "Z"."BATTERY"="ST"."COD_ZAFIRO" AND 
              "Z"."BATTERYEQUIPMENT"="EQ"."COD_ZAFIRO" AND "Z"."BATTERYDISTRICT"="T"."COD_ZAFIRO")
  10 - access(UPPER("S"."WELL")=UPPER("D"."DEVICENAME"))
  16 - filter("T"."GERENCIA"='GOP-2' AND "T"."UG"='GSJ')
  18 - filter("EQ"."DELETED"=0)
  20 - filter("ST"."DELETED"=0)
  21 - access("S"."WELL"="Z"."NAME")

Remote SQL Information (identified by operation id):
----------------------------------------------------

  12 - SELECT "DEVICENAME","TEMPLATE","DELETEFLAG" FROM "DEVICES" "D" WHERE "DELETEFLAG" IS NULL AND 
        "TEMPLATE"='APT' (accessing 'SRVESP.NAPENDP.COM' )

  13 - SELECT "TECHNOLOGY","VARIABLE","TYPE","PARAM1","OPERATOR","PARAM2","COMPARATOR" FROM 
        "CONFIG"."SUGGESTED_VALUES" "SV" WHERE "TECHNOLOGY"='APT' AND TO_NUMBER("TYPE")=1 (accessing 
        'SRVESP.NAPENDP.COM' )

  14 - SELECT "WELL","TYPE" FROM "VM_WELLS_SITU" "S" WHERE "TYPE"='SPECIALWELL' (accessing 
        'SRVHIS.NAPENDP.COM' )

  22 - SELECT "DEVICE","NAME","VALUE" FROM "ESP"."GENERAL_VALUES" "GV" WHERE :1="DEVICE" AND :2="NAME" (accessing 
        'SRVESP.NAPENDP.COM' )
```

Problem is the result set actually brings ~75k rows, not **one**.

Cardinalities should be ~

```
ZAFIRO_SRV_WELLS: 3K
DEVICES: 300
GENERAL_VALUES: 450K
```

Those 3 are **public synonyms**, the last two are pointing at *remote tables*.

Since the optimizer expects them to have only one row, it uses cartesian joins.

As expected, running a cartesian join against a table which in reality has got half a million rows takes forever to complete, so my query becomes useless.

**The problem does NOT replicate in a development environment where all tables belong to the same schema and no synonyms are used**.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are those remote tables Oracle or other DBMS? Have you analyzed them lately?

Comment: Yes, they are Oracle. They all were analyzed an hour ago

Answer (score 0):

In short, you cannot analyze a remote table. You must explicitly gather statistics using DBMS_STATS package.

> The schema object to be analyzed must be local, and it must be in your
>   own schema or you must have the ANALYZE ANY system privilege.

Here is a link to the relevant Oracle doc:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_4005.htm#SQLRF01105